# $J[y]=\int_a^bF(x,y,y')dx$ with constraint and free boundary

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Suppose the variation problem 
$$J[y]=\int_a^bF(x,y,y')dx$$
with free boundary and constraint $\int_a^bG(x,y,y')=l$, how can formulate the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation?

---

For fixed boundary i.e. $f(a)=A, f(b)=B$, the Euler-Lagrange equation is 
$$F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}+(G_y-\frac{d}{dx}G_{y'})=0$$

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/115_fall_06/lagrange_multiplier.pdf

Answer (score 0):

OP's variational problem (v1) is in general ill-posed to begin with.

*Example:* Let for simplicity

$$G(x,y,y^{\prime}) ~=~y^{\prime} \quad\text{and}\quad F(x,y,y^{\prime})~=~2yy^{\prime}  $$

be total derivatives. Then

$$ \ell~=~y(b)-y(a)\quad\text{and}\quad J[y]~=~~y(b)^2-y(a)^2~=~\ell(y(b)+y(a))~=~\ell(\ell +2y(a)), $$

which clearly doesn't have a minimum nor a maximum as there's [free boundary conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_boundary_problem).